# Error : Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {user})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting up the authentication flow  for my app using context API

````
const AuthContext = createContext({
});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user: "Abdullah" }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}```

Error that I am getting is : : Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead
````

Comment: how did you import the `AuthProvider`

Comment: @fadiomar
App.js
`import AuthProvider from "./hooks/useAuth";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Navigation />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
`
Navigation.jsx
`

Comment: try this 
```
export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user: "Abdullah" }} {...props}>
  );
};
```

Comment: ```import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ChatScreen from "./ChatScreen";
import Home from "./Home";
import LoginScreen from "./LoginScreen";

function Navigation() {
  const user = "false";
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        {user ? (
          <>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/chat" element={<ChatScreen />} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginScreen />} />
        )}</Routes></div>);}export default Navigation;
```

Comment: I am so sorry I am a naive dev....
I don't know how to format the code on SOF

Comment: @fadiomar
LoginScreen.jsx
```import React from "react";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";

function LoginScreen() {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  console.log("Hello");
  console.log(user);
  return <div>LoginScreen</div>;
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: in your navigation instead of `<Route path="/chat" element={<ChatScreen />`
try `<Route path="/chat" component={ChatScreen} />`, update all routes

Comment: @fadiomar 
Still same error

Comment: I think the issue is with `<Navigation />` , can you replace it with any static element for now to determine the bug let say `<p> this is test </p>`

Comment: @fadiomar
Still getting the same error
```import AuthProvider from "./hooks/useAuth";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <p>This is test</p>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue here that you are export default the `useAuth` function and also export AuthProvider .
but on your App you are importing AuthProvider as a default export.
`import AuthProvider from "./hooks/useAuth";`
so instead it should be `import {AuthProvider} from "./hooks/useAuth";`